# jquery trouble - onclick for gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, gallery

I am trying to use image gallery for my website that I found [here](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/shinetime/). I want to add one more functionality to this gallery.. I want a large image to be linked and when clicked on it to open in new tab url that is defined in code.
I have included the full code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 /*Your ShineTime Welcome Image*/
 var default_image = 'images/large/default.jpg';
 var default_caption = 'Welcome to my portfolio';
 /*Load The Default Image*/
 loadPhoto(default_image, default_caption);
 function loadPhoto($url, $caption)
 {
    /*Image pre-loader*/
    showPreloader();
    var img = new Image();
    jQuery(img).load( function()
    {
        jQuery(img).hide();
        hidePreloader();
    }).attr({ "src": $url });
    $('#largephoto').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
    $('#largephoto').data('caption', $caption);
 }
 /* When a thumbnail is clicked*/
 $('.thumb_container').click(function()
 {
      var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
      var newsrc  = handler.attr('src');
      var newcaption  = handler.attr('rel');
      loadPhoto(newsrc, newcaption);
 });
 /*When the main photo is hovered over*/
 $('#largephoto').hover(function()
 {
    var currentCaption  = ($(this).data('caption'));
    var largeCaption = $(this).find('#largecaption');
    largeCaption.stop();
    largeCaption.css('opacity','0.9');
    largeCaption.find('.captionContent').html(currentCaption);
    largeCaption.fadeIn()
     largeCaption.find('.captionShine').stop();
     largeCaption.find('.captionShine').css("background-position","-550px 0");
     largeCaption.find('.captionShine').animate({backgroundPosition: '550px 0'},700);
     Cufon.replace('.captionContent');
 },
 function()
 {
    var largeCaption = $(this).find('#largecaption');
    largeCaption.find('.captionContent').html('');
    largeCaption.fadeOut();
 });
 /* When a thumbnail is hovered over*/
 $('.thumb_container').hover(function()
 {
     $(this).find(".large_thumb").stop().animate({marginLeft:-7, marginTop:-7},200);
     $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").stop();
     $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").css("background-position","-99px 0");
     $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").animate({backgroundPosition: '99px 0'},700);
 }, function()
 {
    $(this).find(".large_thumb").stop().animate({marginLeft:0, marginTop:0},200);
 });
 function showPreloader()
 {
   $('#loader').css('background-image','url("images/interface/loader.gif")');
 }
 function hidePreloader()
 {
   $('#loader').css('background-image','url("")');
 }
  });

 </script>
```

And I have 15 thumbnails/photos like this:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <br><br><br>
    <!-- start entry-->
    <div class="thumbnailimage">
        <div class="thumb_container">
            <div class="large_thumb">
                <img src="images/thumbnails/sample1.jpg" class="large_thumb_image" alt="thumb">
                <img alt="" src="images/large/sample1.jpg" class="large_image" rel="Image Sample">
                <div class="large_thumb_border"> </div>
                <div class="large_thumb_shine"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end entry-->
</div>
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, all you have to do is add data-large attributes to each image and on hover it displays a tooltip with the large image inside.

http://jsfiddle.net/DSjLk/

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I'm asking for... I don't want hover effect, I just want to link the large photo and when I click on it to open in a new tab url that is defined in code... I have tried to link it in html, but it didn't work, so it must be done somehow in javascript with onclick event I guess.